# How to calculate lower & upper quartiles?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I'm sure this has been asked many times before but it's confusing me a lot so hopefully someone can help!

I am given this data set:

$ \begin{array} {r}
& 0.28 &0.30& 0.42& 0.59 &0.71 &1.67 \\
& 1.82 & 2.39 & 4.71 &4.79 & 4.89 & 5.00 \\
& 5.00 & 5.76 & 6.09 &6.17 & 6.81& 7.12\\
 &7.44& 8.05 &8.59 & 8.86 & 9.04 & 9.78
 \end{array}$

There are $24$ numbers here. I need to find the lower & upper quartile. I figured that the median is $5.00$.

And looking at the answer sheet the Lower Quartile is $1.745$ and the Upper quartile is $7.28$.

My question is how do i get to these answers!?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give the definition of quartiles and try to describe what you don't understand?

Comment: From my understand the lower quartile(LQ) is the median of the lower half of the set. The upper quartile(UQ) is the median of the upper half of the set. The set is divided into halves by the median of the entire set. I'm having trouble getting the answer of the LQ and UQ to be the same as the answers sheet.

Comment: This is how you find the lower quartile. List down the data for the lower half (excluding the median). Note that we have an even number of data values, so, it is important to note that the median (which is 5.00) we are referring to is the one between 5.00 and 5.00 (in the list you have provided). So, the data for the lower half (excluding the median) is 0.28 0.30 0.42 0.59 0.71 1.67 1.82 2.39 4.71 4.79 4.89 5.00. The median, given by $\frac{1.67+1.82}{2}$ for this data is your lower quartile. Repeat the same procedure for the upper half to get the upper quartile.

Comment: Ahhhh i see. I wasn't including the 5.00 when trying to figure it out as i didn't know the median was between them. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Radz please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are 24 values, and you have already ordered them.
The 12th and 13th values are 5.00, so the median is indeed 5.00.

The lower quartile is indeed the median of the lower half.
Since there are 12 numbers in the lower half, the median is the average of the 6th and the 7th one, which is exactly 1.745.
If there were an odd number of items, you could simply take the middle one.
(Typically the middle one of an even number of entries is taken to be the average of the two middle ones.)

I leave it to you to check that this method gives the answers you are supposed to get.

Comment: Also see the comment by Radz to the question itself, which was written at the same time with this one.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! :)